# How to add context menu handler in DraftJS?

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

Simple props pass does**n't** work.

```
<Editor
  ...
  onContextMenu={handleContextMenu}
/>
```

The only solution I see so far is adding custom block render function and handle context menu for each block. But this solution looks kinda ugly tho...

Another solution is simply put editor into `div` and bind context menu to it.

Comment: it not about draftjs, but how you do context menu in web front

Comment: @JiangYD I just thought that draftjs editor will allow me to pass props to its root component, but apparently it doesn't.

Comment: no it does not.